# How to query row containing the given element inside a JSON column in Laravel PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.3

All I have is a PostgreSQL table that has a JSON column called `agents`.
See below:

```
SELECT agents FROM cnms_rosters;
```

Result:

```
      agents      
------------------
 [1,13,3,16,15]
 [12,13,14,15,15]
 [11,73,55,16,44]
(3 rows)
```

This column contains the id of an agent. What I want to do is to query the row or rows that has the specific agent id.

How can I achieve that?

I am currently using Laravel framework. Is there any Eloquent approach in querying the data? If not, how to query it using `DB::raw` or other query builder?

Comment: Please add your table schema

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id, a from (SELECT Id,
  json_array_elements(r.agents) A
   FROM Cnms_rosters r) ra 
   Where A::TEXT = '13';
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/eb400/19